# No Wifi connection after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, windows-10-upgrade

Upgraded from Win-7 to Win-10. Ethernet connection works, but I can't find any Wifi adapters in the device manager. I didn't change the hardware, and before upgrading WLAN access worked. And I need WLAN because I don't have ethernet in my office.

I read all similar questions in this forum, but nothing helped. Since the adapter isn't found, it doesn't seem to be a driver problem. Nevertheless, I installed the drivers from the CD that came with the pc, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Perhaps the card has become disconnected internally and upgrading to Windows 10 was a coincidence... otherwise are there any other devices in device manager that are showing errors? If the Wifi card is behind a PCIe or USB bridge that doesn't have drivers then it might not show up.

Comment: @Mokubai: no, all devices show up, and there are no error signs. What do you mean by "behind a PCIe or USB bridge"? Is that something that shouldn't have caused troubles already in my previous Win-7?

Comment: Then maybe open the machine up and make sure that the Wifi card is well seated and the contacts are clean. You manufacturer should have a manual showing how to perform maintenance.

Comment: @Mokubai: I found the solution: the reason was the mobile router I use.  So all the time I looked an the wrong place. Anyhow: thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score -2):

Since the Wireless card does not show up in Device Manager, it is likely the card is not compliant with Windows 10. I suggest you get a USB Wireless Card (Best Buy or wherever) and use that instead.

Comment: thanks, but my pc is not very old. I think that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Try running the Network Troubleshooter (Start, Settings, Network, and then Troubleshooter on the right hand side.  It still may be worth your while to try another card.

Comment: I did it. In the first step it wants me to attach an ethernet cable (which I don't have in my office), and in the next step it simply states that there is no network cable attached.

Comment: I am running a bit short of ideas, as the card is just not there in Windows 10 Device Manager.  So at this point, probably best to try a different device for comparison

Comment: problem solved. Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: So how did you solve it? You can write an answer to your own question.

Comment: Did we help you?  Is there an answer we can post ?